# What happens to the corpse of a re-died risen if brought across the boundary?

Tags: glitch

In *Glitch*, some of the risen die again.

> Maria is killed by Vic, who hides her body in the trunk of his car. She's later buried by Kirstie and Charlie.

> Vic is shot by James on the bridge. His body is buried as well by Kirstie and Charlie.

When regular risen near the boundary, they start bleeding from their eyes. The only risen ever to cross the boundary, Carlo, turns to dust.

**Would the bodies of the dead-again risen have turned to dust as well, if carried across the boundary?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as a matter of fact. In the final episode of season 2, "The Letter", James and Beau are transporting

> Paddy's corpse

in the back of a car, when suddenly it begins to turn to dust, presumably because they've crossed the border.